# Developing a 64 bit kernel module on a 32 bit distro

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

My development machine has a 64 bit proc, running a 32 bit distribution.
I would like to compile and test a kernel module with a 64 bit kernel. My question is :

- Is there a 64 bit liveCD **with kernel development package included** ?
- If it does not exist, How can I build a module for a 64 bit kernel ? Then I can eventually test it with a liveCD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a 64-bit VM on a 32-bit operating system, provided the CPU supports it. I know this is possible with VMWare, don't know about anything else.

If you're doing *any* system development nowadays, I'd say use a VM, regardless of the target platform. Just use a VM.

Comment: There are other VM to be used on Linux: I use qemu (kvm-qemu) which is integrated in the Linux kernel, and VirtualBox works too.

+1 for 'Just use a VM', even if this is much more complex if you are writing a driver for real hardware!

Comment: If writing a driver for real hardware, if it's USB you can "pass through" the USB to a VM guest. Otherwise, you're probably out of luck and need real tin. However in this instance, I would have several machines - do not run your editor and test the kernel on the same real box.

Comment: It is for USB. Which VM have this pass through options ?

Comment: VirtualBox certainly has a USB pass through

Comment: It seems USB performance when running as a pass through is different, since our hardware does not work (yet). Not enough bandwith I guess

Answer (score 1):

It might be more technical than you would want to try, but, if you can get a 64bit toolchain installed, you should be able to compile the kernel through:

```
make ARCH=amd64 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- menuconfig
```

You should be able to boot your regular 32bit userland with a 64bit kernel (if you select the appropriate binary compatibility options)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download has links for 64-bit download, and the "make USB on windows" option includes screenshots showing how to make a bootable 64-bit ubuntu USB memory stick. (None of the other options in the {CD, USB} x {Windows, Mac, Ubuntu} instructions mention anything about only working for x86 vs x86-64.)

Comment: I know there are tons of liveCD, I am looking for CD with kernel-devel packages included

Comment: Ah, `apt-get build-dep linux-image-server` probably would require a ton of RAM...